# Why is my fetch promise being stored in the prop as empty instead of the json i'm fetching?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, promise, fetch

I'm trying to grab json from my backend to fill a table on the front end. Nothing is loading and in the react debugging tools it says the table prop is empty.

I've added async to the function that is doing the fetching, but it still seems to pass the json to the prop before its finished (not totally sure).

EDIT: lines are missing in the code because I cut out what was irrelevent

in app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Table from './Table'

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        const repos = getGitHubRepos()
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <Table repoData={repos} />
            </div>
        )   
    }   
}   

async function getGitHubRepos() {
    const response = await fetch('valid url i'm hiding')
    return await response.json()
}   

export default App
```

in table.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Table extends Component {
    render() {
        const { repoData } = this.props

        return (
            <table>
                <TableHeader />
                <TableBody repoData={repoData} />
            </table>
        )
    }
}


const TableBody = props => {
    const rows = props.repoData.map((row, index) => {
        return (
            <tr key={index}>
                <td>{row.name}</td>
                <td>{row.lang}</td>
            </tr>
        )
    })

    return <tbody>{rows}</tbody>

}

export default Table
```

I expect the output to map each bit of json into the table but it isn't doing that because the prop is empty when it gets to table.js

Comment: It shouldn't be "empty". An `async` function always returns a promise. `repoData` should be a promise.

Comment: Every `async` function should be called using `await`. You are calling `const repos = getGitHubRepos()` without it. Also every `await` should be inside in an `async` function

Comment: Setting a function as `async` and using `await` inside only makes execution inside the function wait for resolution, it does not block execution of code outside it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform `async` tasks in an `async componentDidMount` method:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { repos: [] };
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    const repos = await getGitHubRepos();
    this.setState({ repos });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <Table repoData={this.state.repos} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

async function getGitHubRepos() {
  const response = await fetch("valid url Im hiding");
  return response.json();
}

export default App;
```

Be adviced `async/await` syntax is [not covered](https://caniuse.com/#feat=async-functions) by all browsers

Comment: Using this solution I got a failed to compile error './src/App.js
  Line 18:34:  'repos' is not defined  no-undef', line 18 is the <Table repoData={repos} />, is there a specific reason why this is happening?

Comment: Forgot to change that. `repos` is available at state. So we need to use `this.state.repos`

Answer (score 1):

Move your fetching logic in one of Reacts life-cycle methods I would suggest componentDidMount, you should never fetch anything in the render method, you should even avoid extensive calculations there.. after you get the data I would save it in the local component state with this.setState({someState: data}) .. when the state is changed your component will automatically re render. You can read you data from you component state this this.state.someState

You get a thenable promise from fetch you can use .then(function () {}) to define what happens when the data is fetched

```
 function getGitHubRepos() {
     fetch('valid url i'm hiding')
     .then(function (res) {
        this.setState({data: res.data}); // or something similar
      });
  }
```